# Force keyboard to english language on windows phone 7.5

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am trying to force the keyboard language to be English only irrespective of the culture of the app running on **windows phone 7.5**. I tried to hide that language button of the keyboard with various input scope but no input scope provides that facility.

How can I force the keyboard to be in English language only irrespective of the culture of the application?

Answer (score 0):

Keyboard language is a global preference. On Windows Phone 7 and 8, third-party apps have no impact whatsoever on global preferences. So there's no way to do what you're asking.

Comment: is it possible on other platforms ? either on windows phone 8.0 or 8.1 or on uwp ?

Comment: @Supadhyay  When I said "Windows Phone 7 and 8", I was including Windows Phone 8 ;)  I don't know for UWP

Comment: is it possible to create a custom keyboard ? and if yes then provide me some link or project reference and will it be accepted in market ?